# Does the PATH train keep to schedule?

Tags: transit, new-york-city, new-jersey

I think that almost all New Yorkers know that the subway schedule (not real-time arrivals) is [almost always worthless](http://gothamist.com/2017/06/18/surprise_only_two_subway_lines_are.php) - I wouldn't be surprised if many people didn't even know that there *is* a schedule. What about the PATH train? Can the schedule be relied on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [these notes from a 2016 meeting of the PATH Riders' Council](https://www.panynj.gov/path/pdf/PATH_PRC_Minutes-November-2016.pdf), PATH trains run on time 96–97% of the time:

> Mike Marino welcomed the group with opening comments, thanking them for their
>   ongoing support and contribution to PATH.
>
> He provided an overview and update of the ongoing work that has been completed to
>   date during the weekend service outage of the 33rd Street line and that the work was
>   on schedule and within budget. Mike explained that in October he testified on
>   Positive Train Control (PTC) to the NJ State Senate to help them learn more about the
>   intricacies of PTC.
>   Some additional points noted were:
>
> - PATH assisted NJ Transit after the Hoboken train accident with Press, Police
>     and Emergency Command, which is good for building a closer relationship.
> - PATH capital plan and budget were approved by the Port Authority Board of
>     Commissioners.
> - WPIX (PIX 11) broadcast their live morning show on the Journal Square
>     Plaza on November 16, 2016.
> - PATH anticipates 80 MM riders this year and **trains are currently running with
>     96-97 percent on-time performance.**
> - There is a new project underway to build a permanent concrete seawall along
>     the Passaic River which meets FEMA requirements.
> - Plans are progressing to buy additional train cars and overhaul the existing
>     fleet to accommodate growing development.
> - The Port Authority Capital Plan contains $199 MM for PATH.

(Mike Marino has been the [Director of Rail Transit (PATH)](http://www.panynj.gov/press-room/press-item.cfm?headLine_id=2245) at the Port Authority since 2015.)

Comment: Do they define on-time performance as arriving at the last stop within five minutes of the scheduled time, as many other systems including the NYC subway do?  If so, the schedules might still need to be taken with the proverbial grain of salt.  My experience on the lines to Hoboken suggests that they're within a minute or two of the schedule most of the time, but the Newark and Journal Square lines are much longer, so there is more opportunity for delay.

Comment: @phoog: Unclear.  I dug around on the Port Authority website for a while but was unable to find something like an annual report that gave more detail on the above statistic, or broke it down by line.  There's probably room for someone else (you?) to give another answer using local knowledge.